Reset ForEach-Loop in SwiftUi, on Button pressed
I'm trying to reset the following Loop with a Button on the FeedEndCard, but can't get it to work. With reset I mean, that the fist item of the Loop should (re-)appear on the screen an the loop behaves exactly like ists the first run through it.
ForEach(Array(feed.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { (index, context) in
                            
                            
                            let isCurrent = selectedIndex == index
                            let isNext = (selectedIndex + 1) == index
                            let isPrev = (selectedIndex - 1) == index
                            
                            if isCurrent || isNext || isPrev {
                                let offsetValue = cardOffsets[context.intId]
                                
                                userProfileCell(context: context, index: index)
                                    .zIndex(Double(feed.count - index))
                                    .offset(x: offsetValue == nil ? 0 : offsetValue == true ? 900 : -900)
                                
                                if selectedIndex == feed.count {
                                    FeedEndCard(resetPressed: **How to reset the Loop here**)
                                }
                                
                            }
                            
                        }

the Code of the FeedEndCard is this:
struct FeedEndCard: View {
    
    @State private var cardFrame: CGRect = .zero
    var resetPressed : (() -> Void)?


    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                
                endFeedCell
                    .frame(height: cardFrame.height)
                
                
            }
        }
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        .background(.feedLightYellow)
        .cornerRadius(32)
        .readingFrame { frame in
            cardFrame = frame
        }
    }
    
    private var endFeedCell: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
            
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundStyle(.feedYellow)
                .cornerRadius(32)
            
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing:8) {
                Text("End of Feed")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
               
                
                Button {
                    resetPressed
                } label: {
                    TagPillView(iconName: "arrow.counterclockwise", text: "Von vorne Starten")
                }
                
            }
            .padding(24)
            .font(.callout)
            .fontWeight(.medium)
            .foregroundStyle(.feedWhite)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)            
        }
    }
}


I already tried to do something like selectedIndex = 0, but this didn't work. I also tried to adjust the index, but since it is a let constant i got stuck with that also.

The resetPressed should reset the feed array with one element and set selectedIndex to what index will now have this element.

@Ptit Xav thank you for your comment. Unfortunately this doesn’t solve the problem (or I understood your solution wrong)

You shouldn't use offset as an identifier in a ForEach unless the array is completely static. In terms of showing the first item again, add it to the end of the array. So, your ForEach would look like ForEach(items + [items.first].compactMap { $0 }), for example

ForEach is a View not a for loop, see the docs for how to supply it data.
